# A <Router> may have only one child element Error in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am very new to react learning, I have started working with  **Router** in `react.js`.
When I am trying to make Router I am getting this error `A <Router> may have only one child element Error in react`.

My code is as follows:

File : **Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

File : **App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import Stuff from "./Stuff";
import Contact from "./Contact";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <HashRouter>
      <div>
        <div>
          <h1>Simple SPA</h1>
          <ul className="header">
           <li><NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/stuff">Stuff</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
          </ul>
          </div>
         <div className="content">
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route path="/stuff" component={Stuff}/>
            <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    );
  }
} export default App;
```

There are separate files for Home.js, Stuff.js and Contact.js.

I have even tried to use `Switch`, but still getting the same error.
Can anybody suggest what's going wrong here?

Comment: Your code is working fine for me, without any changes. Check it out here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/38zryy518q

Comment: @Shishir : it's not working on my local environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your App.js looks fine. That really strange. Are you sure you have built this code?

You may try to change your index.js to:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<HashRouter><App /></HashRouter>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

And remove `HashRouter` from App.js. Check if it helps.

Comment: No idea. Maybe webpack did not build it or something. Your code looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

I've just encountered this exact same error and it's because I copy-pasted some code which had non breaking space characters (U+00A0) instead of spaces, so extra text nodes were being generated! After replacing with actual spaces, everything worked!

Comment: Thanks for this. You saved my day. Or whatever was left of it, after wasting so much time.